# Bootstrap horizontal form "control-label" not using responsive styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using the "form-horizontal" class with Bootstrap 2, but my labels don't seem to be utilizing the Responsive styling. This is what it looks like:

[image]

When I examine it, it specifically has "width:160px" on the label, which is the regular Bootstrap setting, but the Responsive styling just has "width:auto".

My HTML for that section looks like this:

```
<form id="addproject" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap.css` must be loaded before the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file.

Answer (score 1):

.control-label is only specified in responsive.css for (max-width: 480px). Have you tried shrinking the width way down?  When I use the forms, they look like your example until 480px, at which point the labels move above the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change as you add the class

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="span3" />
```

Another solution is to directly specify a style ID width: auto

```
#title {
    width_auto;
}
```

Remember that your new style should be after the bootstrap css

Comment: The problem isn't my styles or on the input.  The problem is that Bootstrap puts width:160px on the Label, but Bootstrap Responsive puts width:auto on the Label and it's not picking up the Bootstrap Responsive value.