# Labels with inputfields next to each other not responsive in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning bootstrap 4 and I have made a contact form with labels and inputs fields.

This is my code for structure and styling:

```
 <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-12">           
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4 mt-3">     
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">NAME</label>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input class="form-control rounded-0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-3">NAME</label>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input class=" form-control rounded-0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>                      
                    </div>    
                    <div class="col-4 mt-3">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">NAME</label>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input class="form-control rounded-0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">NAME</label>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input  class="form-control rounded-0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">NAME</label>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input a class="form-control rounded-0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">NAME</label>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input  class="form-control rounded-0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 mt-3">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">NAME</label>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <input  class="form-control rounded-0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-3 col-form-label">NAME</label>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <textarea  class="form-control rounded-0"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is when I resize the browser it isn't responsive. The input field goes over the label.

I have made a jsfiddle so you can see the behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/mkgvape9/1/

Sources I use:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_get_started.asp

[Bootstrap horizontal form "control-label" not using responsive styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804741/bootstrap-horizontal-form-control-label-not-using-responsive-styling)

How can I make the label and input field responsive?

Comment: _“ The input field goes over the label.”_ - visually maybe, but technically what is actually happening, is that the width provided by the `.col-3` class at some point simply isn’t enough any more to contain your label text, so that text gets cut off. You would have to switch to a class with a higher “column count” for the low-width resolutions here, or use one of the `col-xy-3` classes here, so that the label can move _aboove_ the input field here (so that they display in a “row” of their own each.)

Comment: I have changed all the labels to `col-xy-3` it goes now under the label!

Comment: (I did of course not mean `xy` _literally_, but that you insert one of the breakpoint “abbreviations” bootstrap uses in that place …)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this HTML structure..

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-12">           
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 mt-3">                 

        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <label class="col-form-label pr-3">NAME</label>
          <div>
            <input class="form-control rounded-0" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <label class="col-form-label pr-3">NAME</label>
          <div>
            <input class=" form-control rounded-0" />
          </div>
        </div>                      
      </div>

      <div class="col-4 mt-3">
        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <label class="col-form-label pr-3">NAME</label>
          <div>
            <input class="form-control rounded-0" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <label class="col-form-label pr-3">NAME</label>
          <div>
            <input  class="form-control rounded-0" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <label class="col-form-label pr-3">NAME</label>
          <div>
            <input a class="form-control rounded-0" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <label class="col-form-label pr-3">NAME</label>
          <div>
            <input  class="form-control rounded-0" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 mt-3">
        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <label class="col-form-label pr-3">NAME</label>
          <div>
            <input  class="form-control rounded-0" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group d-flex flex-wrap">
          <label class="col-form-label pr-3">NAME</label>
          <div>
            <textarea  class="form-control rounded-0"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is responive only the labels and input are not next to each other

Comment: Small mobile devices are 320px wide. So, if you want to get better look in mobile devices, you have two options. *1) You have to stack input field down to the label....* But You really want to set input fields next to labels *2) You have to stack fields columns.* Which option do you prefer?

Comment: I have set HTML Structure as per first option. For second option replace `class="col-4 mt-3"` with `class="col-lg-4 mt-3" (stack from 991px and below)` or `class="col-md-4 mt-3" (stack from 767px and below)`